# How can i instantly update the parent height with framer motion using react?

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

For my personal usage, i created a slider component with react and framer motion. The Structure looks like this:

```html
<!-- App.tsx -->
<Slider className="bg-white shadow sm:rounded-lg flex flex-row overflow-hidden">
  <Slide>
    <TestSlide1 />
  </Slide>
  <Slide>
    <TestSlide2 />
  </Slide>
</Slider>
```

to switch between the slides, i am using `React.Children.toArray()` in my `Slider` Component like this:

```js
// Slider Component
const childrenArray = React.Children.toArray(children) as React.ReactElement<SlideProps>[]
const [[page, direction], setPage] = useState([0, 0])
const currentChild = childrenArray[page] as React.ReactElement<SlideProps>

const paginate = (newDirection: number) => {
  setPage([page + newDirection, newDirection])
}
```

and i render the `currentChild` like this:

```html
<!-- Slider Component -->
return (
  <motion.div layout className={className}>
    <AnimatePresence initial={false} custom={direction}>
      {React.cloneElement(currentChild, {
        key: page,
        variants: variants,
        custom: direction,
        transition: transition,
        paginate: paginate,
      })}
    </AnimatePresence>
  </motion.div>
)
```

to get `framer-motion` working, i pass there specific props `variants` `custom` `transition` to the `Slide` Component using `React.cloneElement()`

It works, but i have a problem with the animation. As you noticed, i am using the `layout` prop inside my `Slider` Component. The `layout` prop animates automatically this component to its new position when its layout changes, in my case the height. However, when I navigate to the next slide, I have a delay in this animation. The slide is changed and only then the height is animated. How can I fix this?

**Demo**

for better understanding, you can find a demo on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-slider-height-issue-3yhqo)

Comment: Are you saying that you want the height of slider to animate as the current slide changes. IE  as the height of it's content changes?

Comment: yes, but how can I do that?